# Smart code completion in Qt Creator

Tags: c++, qt-creator, code-completion

Is Qt Creator present smart code completion like Intellij IDEA? For example:

```
void main() {
    QString simpleVariableName = "First string";
    QString anotherVariableName = "Second string";
    // If I type "variable" and press Ctrl + Space I would like to get 
    // all matching variables(simple and another) in popup list. In 
    // IDEA it works, but Qt Creator show nothing.
}
```

I heard aboud Clang Code Model plugin and it's already installed in my 3.4.0 version. But it make no sense, I still have a default behaviour.

Is there any way to get really smart code completion?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Is there any way to get really smart code completion?**

Well, the answer to your question is Yes. You could implement a plugin or add that feature to an existing one. But, right now, the only plugin that comes by default in the QtCreator and deals with code completion is ClangCodeModel.

The ClangCodeModel plugin does not have such feature.

On the other hand, having the plugin installed is not enough to get it working, you need to enable it.

Go to `Help` -> `About Plugins` and make sure the checkbox "Load" for the ClangCodeModel plugin is checked.

The plugin improve code completion, but be aware this plugin is experimental and is not complete.

[image: Checkbox for the ClangCodeModel plugin is checked!]

**Links of interest:**

[Code completion is not so smart.](https://forum.qt.io/topic/53669/code-completion-is-not-so-smart)

[Clang based code model](http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.comp.lib.qt.creator/9784)

Comment: Thaks for reply. As I said, I already have installed and activated Clang-code model [here it is](http://imgur.com/CnVlArj) . The point is: this plugin _really_ not too smart and have pure(for 2015) functionality. Also, thanks for the links.